# How to handle data source between custom audience creation and add user to custom audience

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am using graph/marketing API v2.8 and using code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-api/v2.8 for creating custom audience and adding user in custom audience.

With this code, I can successfully create custom audience but when I try to add user to custom audience then it gives following error.

```
Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source EVENT_BASED.WEB_PIXEL_HITS, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS
```

I can also give sample code that I am trying but I am using same code mentioned in above link.

Anyone can you please tell me, What can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, I guess you should set `sub_type` to `CUSTOM`, not `WEB_PIXELS_HITS`. Below example uses Java SDK:

```
CustomAudience audience = account.createCustomAudience()
    .setName("Created by Java SDK")
    .setDescription("Test Custom Audience")
    .setSubtype(EnumSubtype.VALUE_CUSTOM)
    .execute();
```